# MIMIC III medications

Tags: mimic-iii

The prescriptions table, only has information, about the dose, medication name and days between which (i assume inclusive) the medication was ordered (not even sure if this corresponds to actual administration)... this is too crude for meaningful research analysis received medications dosing.

Is there any other way, that this information could be saved ?

For example doses of IV gtts. are generally retrievable from the 
inputevents_cv  and inputevents_mv.

But how about lets say prednisone doses patient received ? 
Any one figured that out ?
How to calculate sum of the dose of prednisone given orally during patients ICU stay ?